# Failed to initialise Edge browser control

Tags: delphi, microsoft-edge, twebbrowser, microsoft-edge-chromium, tedgebrowser

Having a hard time attempting to run an example how to use `TEdgeBrowser` component on Windows 10.

Using the latest RAD Studio 10.4.1 (27.0.38860.1461)

The example is located under this path:

`c:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Samples\Object Pascal\VCL\WebBrowser\Edge\`

Attempting to start results in "Failed to initialise Edge browser control".

What I tried:

- Installed the latest stable Edge version (88.0.705.68 (Official build) (64-bit))
- Downloaded and installed the runtime from
  `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/`
- Downloaded this:
  `https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2/1.0.705.50`
- Extracted `WebView2Loader.dll` and placed into the same folder where the compiled executable of the above demo resides

The documentation on:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_TEdgeBrowser_Component_and_Changes_to_the_TWebBrowser_Component

Seems to be out of date and refers to old `0.9.430` version. I have actually previously used Edge Canary release with that version of WebView2Loader.dll before and that has worked, but the stable version of Edge Chromium was released in the meanwhile, assuming there were breaking API changes.

So, is it even possible to use `TEdgeBrowser` with Edge Chromium at this point because from all that I've tried it seems pretty hopeless? To me it looks like it is hard-coded against 0.9.430 and RAD Studio 10.4.1 wasn't updated. Is there a workaround of any sort?

Comment: GetIt has an EdgeView2 SDK item available. I don't know if that helps, but also didn't see a mention of it in your post.

Comment: FWIW, I also tried to use the Edge control the other day, followed all of Emba's instructions, and ended up with an AV on application exit. I immediately decided not to use Edge in my Delphi apps.

Comment: @KenWhite if you mean this - https://getitnow.embarcadero.com/EdgeView2SDK-0.9.488/ - this is for the version 0.9.488 and it links to the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2

Answer (score 2):

[image]for solving this copy "WebView2Loader.dll" to your output path

Answer (score 1):

`TEdgeBrowser` requires [`WebView2 Runtime`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section) in order to operate. More details on [MS Edge Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution) website.

`WebView2Loader.dll` should be loadable by your application, in the same folder, known path or registered in `path` environement variable. Latest version is available on [`NuGet`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2). Nupkg is a zip archive. Look in build\native\ folder.

`TEdgeBrowser.BrowserExecutableFolder` should point to `WebView2` runtime folder in case of fixed version.

MS claims that evergreen version will be distributed by default in next Windows versions.